# How can we read properties file in Maven and authenticate wsimport without an authfile?

Tags: java, maven, web-services, properties, wsimport

For generating Web service stub.

Using following to import having authfile which consists of username and password

```
jaxws:wsimport args: [-s, D:\ProjectGit\ProjectProcess\ProjectProsess-wsclient\src\main\generated, -d, D:\ProjectGit\ProjectProcess\ProjectProsess-wsclient\src\main\generated, -verbose, -Xnocompile, -XadditionalHeaders, -Xnocompile, -Xauthfile, D:\ProjectGit\ProjectProcess\ProjectProsess-wsclient/src/main/resources/Authfile, -b, D:\ProjectGit\ProjectProcess\ProjectProsess-wsclient\src\main\resources\Frontend.jaxb, -b, D:\ProjectGit\ProjectProcess\ProjectProsess-wsclient\src\main\resources\jaxws.bindings.xml, http://localhost:8082/ActivityServices?wsdl]
```

Authfile consists of URL in following format:

```
http://username:password@192.11.116.31/bms/ActivityServices?wsdl
```

Username password are same for all list of services in Authfile. So when we build object using maven above credentials are used to authenticate web services

**Current Maven Configuration**:

```
<properties>
  <pom.ule.url>http://localhost:8083/bms/</pom.ule.url>
 <pom.auth.file.path.generate>${basedir}/src/main/resources/Authfile</pom.auth.file.path.generate>
    </properties>
```

In wsimport part above tag is called

```
<args>
                                        <arg>-Xnocompile</arg>
                                        <arg>-Xauthfile</arg>
<!--                                    <arg>${basedir}/src/main/resources/Authfile<arg> -->
                                        <arg>${pom.auth.file.path.generate}</arg>
                                    </args>
```

---

**Requirement**: To remove authfile completely and read username password from configuration file in maven and supply it to wsimport

```
config.properties

username=username
password=password
//otherproperties
```

How is it possible to do so using Maven and wsimport?